# Fit poisson distribution to data and find lambda

Tags: python, poisson

I have two lists X and Y. I am plotting the points and trying to fit a Poisson distribution to it in order to find lambda.

I was looking online but I could not find a way to fit a poussin directly to a scatter.

Here is the data:

```
X = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
Y = [0.10560625814863103, 0.1981747066492829, 0.1258346173600411, 0.09288451661333018, 0.07151041049346134, 0.05906522855675398, 0.04843743826794674, 0.04152344830310932, 0.03381928805657619, 0.027813993915688832, 0.02564102564102564, 0.02078147840859705, 0.01888506973252736, 0.015526846035320611, 0.01252419896487693, 0.012326656394453005, 0.01078582434514638, 0.009086958239500613, 0.008178262415550551, 0.007822685788787484, 0.006123819683141717, 0.0054916834577851525, 0.004464462091580736, 0.003634783295800245, 0.003792817352139386, 0.0038718343803089564, 0.0034372407253763187, 0.0028446130141045393, 0.002647070443680613, 0.0030026470704436806, 0.0022519853028327604, 0.0015408320493066256, 0.0016988661056457667, 0.0014223065070522697, 0.001738374619730552, 0.0009877128521196318, 0.0015408320493066256, 0.0011852554225435582, 0.0010667298802892024, 0.001027221366204417]
```

And the scatter plot:

[image]

Comment: You don't need fancy fitting, the mean for a Poisson is lambda so you just need to calculate/estimate the mean.  Analytically that would be `sum( x * p(x) )`.  I'm assuming that your Y values are observational since they sum to 1 but only go up to X = 39, so the mean won't be exact but will be a decent estimate.  Taking the product of each `(x,y)` pair and summing yields lambda ≈ 5.734.

Comment: Having estimated lambda, when I plot the results against your data it looks unlikely that your Poisson assumption is correct.

Comment: Oh I see what you did there. Thanks a lot for the insight, I will probably need to look into some other distribution that could suit this dataset then